# How do I do this with JAXB?

Tags: jaxb

I can't find anything that spells out to me how to do this on the web, or am not following what I do find, so I thought I would ask here.

I have an XML message that I want to de-serialize to a Java object. The message is of the format:

```
<billing-amount>
    <EUR>100</EUR>
    <GBP>12</GBP>
</billing>
```

The snippet comes from a response to an API request on a payment gateway that I am trying to integrate with. Each node within the `<billing-amount>` node represents an an amount of a given currency. `<EUR>` represents Euros, for example.

Now if I know all of the possible currencies (well, at least the ones I care about) I can create a Java class that has the following fields within it, one for each possible currency:

```
public class BillingAmount {
    @XmlElement(name = "EUR")
    @XmlValue
    private Integer euroAmount

    @XmlElement(name = "EUR")
    @XmlValue
    private Integer euroAmount
    ...
}
```

And I can then use this new class as follows - making it a field of the actual class that is being created from the XML message:

```
@XmlElement(name = "billing-amount")
private BillingAmount billingAmount;
```

The `billingAMount` object, when instantiated, will have one field with the amounts of Euros in it and another with the amount of GBP. Which is all good.

But, What I would like to know is, is there a better way of doing this?  Is is there a way in JAXB to use the name of the node to add properties to a class you are creating? Or to create a class based upon the name of a node in a list?

Essentially what I would like is to create the class based on the name of the node within the list. So the `BillingAcount` class could maybe be replaced with an `XmlElementWrapper` as it seems an overhead to create a class just to act as a container.

Thanks.

Comment: You want a class that holds a collection of prices, where each price is within a element that specifies the currency?

Comment: yes, I believe so. Also, rather than having to create a custom class to act as a container, I would rather that it was a list or some such. Cheers